# onResponse(JSONObject response) not working

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to display records from my database in a `TextView result;`

But I figured out that `public void onResponse(JSONObject response)` is not executing. No record is displayed in Textview . What I am doing wrong here ?

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText firstname, lastname, age;
    Button show;
    TextView result;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;


   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {

                                JSONArray students = response.getJSONArray("students");
                                for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++){
                                    JSONObject student = students.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String firstname = student.getString("firstname");
                                    String lastname = student.getString("lastname");
                                    String age = student.getString("age");

                                    result.append(firstname + " " + lastname + " " + age + "\n");
                                }
                                result.append("....\n");

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        }
                    });

                    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
                }
            });
}
}
```

and i am getting this error message

> 12-30 18:22:12.420 26346-26346/com.example.mememe.loginregister
>   E/Volley: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError:
>   java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80)
>   after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: if it is not going in onResponse then it should be going in Response.ErrorListner. please check it. it goies in error response when yor api gives error

Comment: how can i handle it ?

Comment: If it is going in on error listner. then it could be problem in your api. or you are missing some parameter to pass. because of that, obviously you can not do anything to fill your textview untill you have any response from your api.

Comment: so yes it is going in public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {} 
so how can i resolve this error. i want to display my records
help....

Comment: what do you have in your error variable check.

Comment: i am sorry i did not get your question

Comment: i mean. when you put a break point inside of your errorlistner what you are seeing in your debug screen?

Comment: nothing because i havent written any code in my Response.ErrorListener()

Comment: i am getting this error msg
12-30 18:22:12.420 26346-26346/com.example.mememe.loginregister 
E/Volley: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: What is assigned to `showUrl`? @MiralBhalani  is trying to tell you that `onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)` will get called - put a break point in and analyse the `VolleyError` object for more information.

Comment: @MarkKeen i get this errror 

E/Volley: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

how can i resolve this ?

Comment: String showUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/proj/showRecords.php";

Comment: That IP is the local loopback address - you will get an error if trying to reach that address as it's the device itself.  You meed a valid network address to connect to (the address/ip of your server), either on an internal network that both devices are connected to, or an valid external address, like an ordinary web server.

Comment: so i how do i resolve this i mean how do i get valid network address ?

Comment: That becomes an entirely different question - if you're confident that you have tested your webserver and it works then go live with it.